# Issue with diacritics in Romanian language document

Tags: pdftex, pdf, font-encodings, copy-paste

I have a document that uses Romanian language, characters with diacritics. It is created using TexWorks.
My document looks like this:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}

ca răspuns la anunțul dumneavoastră
```

It looks fine when viewing it in a PDF reader. When I try to copy the text from PDF to notepad, it outputs:

```
ca r˘ aspuns la anunt , ul
```

This is copied instead of the original input. Can someone please shed some light as to why it does this?

Comment: Did  you load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: @Bernard It helps for `ă`, but it won't for `ț`, unfortunately. The only way for getting copyable Romanian text is using XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX, as there's no font supporting the special Romanian characters.

Comment: @Bernard Almost the same:
ca r spuns la anunt , ul dumneavoastr

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is currently no font encoding fully supporting Romanian, I'm afraid. New fonts should be created: not from scratch, but it would be a big job and you'd not have many of them available anyway.

The problem is that in the standard encoding `OT1`, no accented letter is present; with `T1` the situation is slightly better because `ÂâÎîĂă` are present as precomposed characters, but `ȘșȚț` aren't, so they have to be built from other pieces.

This has two bad consequences: Romanian words cannot be hyphenated properly beyond `ȘșȚț` and the characters cannot be safely copied from the PDF. A not really easy workaround for copying is available with the `accsupp` package, which however only works with Adobe Acrobat and no other viewer that I know of.

The `T1` encoding unfortunately has `ŞşŢţ` which are not good enough for good Romanian typography. The reason is historical: when the `T1` encoding was decided upon, support for Turkish was easy to add and the language has `Şş`; the “t” with the cedilla was added (and it was wrong to begin with, in my opinion).

With XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX the situation is much better: many fonts support the Romanian letters `ŞşŢţ` as well as the other ones. The following works out of the box with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

ca răspuns la anunțul dumneavoastră

\end{document}
```

[image]

and copy/paste from the PDF gives

```
ca răspuns la anunțul dumneavoastră
```